# JSON array format in php for android

Tags: php, android, json, parsing

```
<?php
    require "con.php";

    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM registration_data WHERE profession like 'teacher'");

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
         $responce[]=array("name"=>$row[0],"password"=>$row[1]);
    }

    echo JSON_encode(array($responce));
    $responce=array();
?>

//Output of code is: 

[[{"name":"user1","password":"pass1"},{"name":"user2","password":"pass2"}]]
```

JSONArray in android is unable to read this output

what is the proper way to get data from database and store it in `JSON` format so i can use it in `JSONObject` and `JSONArray` in android.

My code in android is as follow:

```
public class FetchData extends AsyncTask {
String data;
String dataParsed="";
String singleParsed="";
@Override
 protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
    try{
        URL url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2/android/test.php");
        HttpURLConnection con= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        InputStream is=con.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line="";

        while(line !=null)
        {
            line=br.readLine();
            data=data+line;
        }

        JSONArray JA=new JSONArray(data);
        singleParsed= String.valueOf(JA.length());
       for(int i=0;i<JA.length();i++)
        {
            JSONObject JO= (JSONObject) JA.get(i);
            singleParsed="name: "+JO.get("name")+" \n"+"password: "+JO.get("email");
            dataParsed=dataParsed+singleParsed;
        }
    }
    catch(MalformedURLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
       return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
       super.onPostExecute(o);
       MapTest.tv.setText(this.data);
    }
}
```

The output of `php` code is shown as it is if i show data variable but i am unable to store and get it in `JSON` array and display in a sequence

Comment: try changing : `while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
         $responce[]=array("name"=>$row[0],"password"=>$row[1]);
    }

    echo JSON_encode(array($responce));` 
to
`while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
         $response["name"]=$row[0];
         $response["password"]=>$row[1];
    }

    echo JSON_encode($responce);`

Comment: `$responce` is already an array. so `json_encode(array($responce));` wraps it in another array. You can just do `json_encode($responce);`

Comment: thankyou @RohitS...

Comment: and yes thanku @RolandStarke the issue was extra arrary() used in json_encode()

Comment: You should define `$responce = array();` before your loop, so in case there are no results, you still echo an empty array and don't get an error.

Comment: Why do you put ```array()``` for echoing the ```$response```?

Comment: replace [ with " " also an option in android